# How to hide fields in qweb report of some module in openerp?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo, qweb

I am customizing Sales module as I have hidden some fields from sales order FORM VIEW. When I go for printing invoice its showing some empty fields those are which I've already made hide in form view.

So I want to make those fields hidden in reports also. What is the methodology to do so, any ideas??

```
Reference:
Sales/Quotations/ print : sale.report_saleorder.pdf
```

In that, I want to hide Taxes field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide those fields you want in the report almost the same way you did in form view. Create a XML file in views folder and add it to `__openerp__.py`. Start your file this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_saleorder_document_customized" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
        ...
```

From here on you must use `xpath` tag to locate your items, and make them invisible in the same way you do in a simple form view (using `position="attributes"/"replace"`).

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for hide some part in qweb report.

Here, I want to hide tax table and Changed string value and also hide payment term of Inovice report.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_document_inherit" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_documnet">
            <!-- Changed 'Draft Invoice' to 'Tax Invoice' and 'Invoice' to 'Tax Invoice'-->
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/h2/span[1]" position="replace">
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and (o.state in ('draft', 'open', 'paid'))">Tax Invoice</span>
            </xpath>
            <!-- Hide span -->
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/h2/span[3]" position="replace"/>
            <!--Hide Tax table -->
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/div[4]" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="class">hidden</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <!-- Hide payment term value from invoice report -->
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/p[2]" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="class">hidden</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Hope above code help you.

Best Thanks,

Ankit H Gandhi.